# C programming program expects input when its not asked

Tags: c

Hi I have a program which is a calculator program that calculates the sum, difference or product of two integers. The program asks for the type of calculation first (1 = sum, 2 = difference, 3 = product). After calculation, the result is printed on the screen and the program returns to prompt for the next calculation.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int addition(int a , int b);
int subtraction(int a, int b);
int multiplication(int a , int b);

int main()
{
  int choicea, choiceb, cal;
  do{

    printf("1: sum of two numbers\n2: difference of two numbers\n3: product of two numbers\n");
    printf("<0: terminate the program\n");
    printf("Select calculation:");
    scanf("%d", &cal);
    printf("Enter the first number:");
    scanf("%d", &choicea);
    printf("Enter the second number:");
    scanf("%d", &choiceb);

    if(choicea < 0 || choiceb < 0 ) {
      printf("Terminating the program...");
    }
    else if(cal == 1) {
      addition( choicea , choiceb);
    }
    else if(cal == 2) {
      subtraction(choicea, choiceb);
    }
    else if(cal == 3) {
      multiplication(choicea, choiceb);
    }
    else {
      printf("You entered an invalid number.\n\n");
    }
  }while(cal>0);

  return 0;
}



int addition(int a , int b){
    int cal = a + b ;
    return printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a , b , cal);
}
int subtraction(int a, int b){
    int cal = a - b ;
    return printf("%d - %d = %d\n", a , b , cal);
}
int multiplication(int a , int b){
    int cal = a * b ;
    return printf("%d * %d = %d\n", a , b , cal);
}
```

The complier is given by the tutorial site so its not on my pc and the error I get is this.
[image]

Comment: `return printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a , b , cal);` mind that printf returns the total characters that was written. Hope this is what you wanted to do.

Comment: Your output is not matching what the site expects.  Check the program specifications to ensure you're doing the right thing.  I suspect you're supposed to quit if the result is negative.

Comment: It works fine here, and it seems to work fine on your tutorial site as wellas far as I can see. What makes you think it doesn't work ? What tutorial site is this ?

Comment: Test for termination after the first input.  Also, add a fflush(stdout) before the scanf to make sure the prompt is correct.

Comment: @sjsam the only other thing I did not write that says on the site is this -the functions carrying out the calculations and printing do not take any parameters or return any value.

Comment: @dbush the only other thing I did not write that says on the site is this -the functions carrying out the calculations and printing do not take any parameters or return any value.

Comment: @MichaelWalz the only other thing I did not write that says on the site is this -the functions carrying out the calculations and printing do not take any parameters or return any value.

Comment: @cup the only other thing I did not write that says on the site is this -the functions carrying out the calculations and printing do not take any parameters or return any value.

Comment: The tester sends -1 for the calculation and you still ask for the first number.

Comment: @stark yes, but i dont know what i am doing wrong

Comment: Right after the scanf for cal check if < 0 then do `break;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing out the enter the first number and all those before the if clauses begin, try to make a if statement which checks if the number is negative integer and if so breaks and if not continues with asking the information

```
#include <stdio.h>

int addition(int a , int b);
int subtraction(int a, int b);
int multiplication(int a , int b);

int main()
{
  int choicea, choiceb, cal;
  do{

    printf("1: sum of two numbers\n2: difference of two numbers\n3: product of two numbers\n");
    printf("<0: terminate the program\n");
    printf("Select calculation:");
    scanf("%d", &cal);

    if(cal < 0 ) {
      printf("Terminating the program...");
    }
    else
      {
        printf("Enter the first number:");
            scanf("%d", &choicea);
        printf("Enter the second number:");
            scanf("%d", &choiceb);
        if(cal == 1) {
          addition( choicea , choiceb);
        }
        else if(cal == 2) {
          subtraction(choicea, choiceb);
        }
        else if(cal == 3) {
          multiplication(choicea, choiceb);
        }
        else {
          printf("You entered an invalid number.\n\n");
        }
    }
  }while(cal >= 0 );

  return 0;
}



int addition(int a , int b){
int cal = a + b ;
return printf("%d + %d = %d\n\n", a , b , cal);
}
int subtraction(int a, int b){
int cal = a - b ;
return printf("%d - %d = %d\n\n", a , b , cal);
}
int multiplication(int a , int b){
int cal = a * b ;
return printf("%d * %d = %d\n\n", a , b , cal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a case of bad test logic. Assume you enter cal = (something less than 0). The program should immediately terminate, but you still request more information. You are somewhat handling this with your 'else' statement, but perhaps the test is not satisfied with this solution. Online testers are only so good.

I would use a while loop, and put the calc scanf right in the evaluation of the while.